# How to disable cron jobs in dropwizard

Tags: java, asynchronous, quartz-scheduler, dropwizard

I have some Dropwizard Jobs that run on an scheduled time, but I want to provide to the admin the possibility of enabling and disabling them at runtime. Is there an easy way to do this with dropwizard? Is there something I can do to disable this kind of jobs easier without injecting properties/toggles.

```
  import de.spinscale.dropwizard.jobs.Job;
  import de.spinscale.dropwizard.jobs.annotations.On;

  @On("${someJob}")
  public class MyJob extends Job {
        @Override
         public void doJob(JobExecutionContext context) {
             // do stuff...
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that with these endpoints:

```
@POST
@Path("/my-job")
public void enableJob() throws SchedulerException {
    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).build();
    jobManager.getScheduler().addJob(jobDetail, false);
}

@DELETE
@Path("/my-job")
public void disableJob() throws SchedulerException {
    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).build();
    JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(MyJob.class.getCanonicalName());
    jobManager.getScheduler().deleteJob(jobKey);
}
```

The `JobManager` here is the one you give to Dropwizard with

```
environment.lifecycle().manage(jobManager);
```